# Flutter TextField with controller not updating the field at all

Tags: flutter, dart

I thought I had this right, but evidently something is off. Simple text field with the default text set by the controller to `newUser['firstName']`. `newUser` is of type `Map<String, Dynamic>`

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
    controller: TextEditingController(text: newUser['firstName']), // currently set to "Garrett"
    onChanged: (text) {
        print('TEXT: $text'); // only gives the current value plus the last letter hit, ex. 
        "Garrettr", "Garrettf", etc.

        setState(() {
            newUser['firstName'] = text;
        });

        print('FIRST NAME: ${newUser['firstName']}'); // same as text
    },
),
```

No errors, but when I type in the field to change the text nothing happens and the `newUser['firstName']` will equal "Garrette" or "Garrettr", etc.. As you can see in the code the `text` that comes through `onChanged` doesn't seem to be right, not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: You shouldn't initialise the controller every time. The controller should be initialised once and you can use the controller to get the changed text.

Comment: @danypata and there should be a different controller instance for each textfield that I have? If I have an edit profile screen with more then 20 textfields I can't simplify things with on controller instance?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for you, since you have a lot of fields is to create a "descriptor class" for your fields. Something like this.

```
class InputFieldDescriptor {
  final String key;
  final String placeholder;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  InputFieldDescriptor(this.key, this.placeholder, this.controller);
}

class WidgetThatDisplayFields extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetThatDisplayFields createState() => _WidgetThatDisplayFields();
}

class _WidgetThatDisplayFields extends State<WidgetThatDisplayFields> {
  List<InputFieldDescriptor> _descriptors = [
    InputFieldDescriptor("user_name", "User name", TextEditingController()),
    InputFieldDescriptor("email", "Email", TextEditingController()),
    InputFieldDescriptor("password", "password", TextEditingController()),
  ];

  List<Widget> _inputFields() {
    return _descriptors.map((descriptor) {
      return TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: descriptor.placeholder),
          controller: descriptor.controller); // currently set to "Garrett"
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: _inputFields(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, String> _collect() {
    Map<String, String> data = {};
    _descriptors.forEach((descriptor) {
      data[descriptor.key] = descriptor.controller.text;
    });
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Up on your code before the TextField do initialize something like `final TextEditingController anyThing = new TextEditingController();`

Now to get the new text set `newUser['firstName'] = anyThing.text`

Try this and let me know if you need further help.

So the whole thing would be:

```
final TextEditingController anyThing = new TextEditingController();
TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
        controller: anyThing, // currently set to "Garrett"
        onChanged: (text) {
          print('TEXT: $text'); // only gives the current value plus the last letter hit, ex.

          setState(() {
          newUser['firstName'] = text;
          });

          print('FIRST NAME: ${newUser['firstName']}'); // same as text
        },
      ),
```

Comment: This goes inside the `setState`? what gets passed into the `onChanged` callback? Ould you be able to show a more complete example?